# Number Theory (Q4 BMO 1996)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Define $q(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}\right\rfloor$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Determine with proof all positive integers $n$ for which $q(n)>q(n+1)$.

Claim: Let $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then for all $n=m^2-1$ with $m>1$, $q(n)>q(n+1)$.

Proof:
Observe that since $(m-1)^2<m^2-1<(m+1)^2$  $q(m^2-1)=m+1$. Also $q(m^2)=m$.
Therefore $n=m^2-1$ is a solution.

I need help with proving that it's the only solution. I thought  that since q(n) is increasing  between $n^2$ and $(n+1)$ there cannot be another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rough idea:

If neither $n$ nor $n+1$ are perfect squares, then $\lfloor n\rfloor$ and $\lfloor n+1 \rfloor$ are equal. Let their value be $k$. Now $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor\leq \lfloor\frac{n+1}{k}\rfloor$. So such values of $n$ and $n+1$ can’t be chosen.

So $n=m^2$ or $n=m^2-1$

You can check for the case $n=m^2$, and show that it is impossible.